# Relates OWL individual with OWL axiom

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data, apache-jena

I have to related the `owl:axiom` with the `owl:individual`.

My RDF is as follows:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.sab.org/abbeys#Abbaye_Notre-Dame_de_Maizières_Saint-Loup-de-la-Salle,_Saône-et-Loire">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.sab.org/abbeys#Monastery"/>
        <rdfs:label>Abbaye Notre-Dame de Maizières Saint-Loup-de-la-Salle, Saône-et-Loire</rdfs:label>
        <abbeys:hasFoundationDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1132</abbeys:hasFoundationDate>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
            <owl:Axiom>
        <owl:has_trusted_certainty_degree rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">0.9</owl:has_trusted_certainty_degree>
        <owl:annotatedTarget rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1132</owl:annotatedTarget>
        <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http://www.sab.org/abbeys#hasFoundationDate"/>
        <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http://www.sab.org/abbeys#Abbaye_Notre-Dame_de_Maizières_Saint-Loup-de-la-Salle,_Saône-et-Loire"/>
    </owl:Axiom>
```

I need to relate the `has_trusted_degree` with the foundation date in `owl:individual`.

I tried the following query but it returns nothing:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX : <http://www.sab.org/abbeys#> 
PREFIX xds: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?label  ?trust
WHERE {  
  ?monastery rdfs:label ?label. 
  FILTER(lang(?label) = '')
  OPTIONAL{?monastery :has_trusted_certainty_degree ?trust}
  ORDER BY ?label
```

Can anyone help me in figuring this out?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: RDF/XML tends to make everything more difficult. I recommend reserializing as RDF/Turtle to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Your ontology has a wrong prefix for the property, see this line:

```
<owl:has_trusted_certainty_degree rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">0.9</owl:has_trusted_certainty_degree>
```

I assume that `owl` is the prefix for the OWL vocabulary and not for your user defined namespace. Thus, it shouldn't be `owl:has_trusted_certainty_degree` but the prefix for the namespace `http://www.sab.org/abbeys#`.